# DB2 how to get user privilege information when privilege is granted to its group

Tags: security, db2, privileges

I grant schema CREATEIN privilege for schema '**test**' to user group '**test-group**', then add a user '**test-user**' into this '**test-group**' in Windows OS.

I would like to know what DB2 function or SQL statement can be used to retrieve privilege information for user '**test-user**'. I am aware of that the user-group relationship is not defined in DB2, but there must be some ways to look up such relationship data.

As an example, I can create a table successfully in schema '**test**' after log in database by user '**test-user**' which means the DB2 engine can get 'test-user' CREATEIN privilege inherited from '**test-group**'.

I tried to check syscat.schemaauth view by SQL statment 
 `select * from syscat.schemaauth` but cannot find user '**test-user**' privilege definition only group 'test-group' privilege definition:

```
GRANTOR      GRANTORTYPE  GRANTEE GRANTEETYPE  SCHEMANAME   ALTERINAUTH   CREATEAUTH  DROPINAUTH
...  ....
SYSIBM          S          PUBLIC   G         ADMINISTRATOR N                Y          N
ADMINISTRATOR   U          TEST     G          TEST         N                Y          Y
.. ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the table function [AUTH_LIST_GROUPS_FOR_AUTHID](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0021976.html) to look up the groups for "test-user". That would list **ALL** groups the user belongs to, including OS groups not used for the database.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE (SYSPROC.AUTH_LIST_GROUPS_FOR_AUTHID('TEST-USER')) AS T
```

There is another view, [SYSIBMADM.AUTHORIZATIONIDS](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0021977.html), which lists all authorization IDs, i.e., groups, users and roles:

```
SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.AUTHORIZATIONIDS
```

The last view you need is [SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0021978.html) which lists the privileges. Depending on what you need you would combine the three views/table functions

- look up the user's groups for groups known to the database
- list the privileges for the user AND
- list the privileges for all the groups the user belongs to

UPDATE:
I got interested and quickly typed up and tested a query. This should answer it directly. The "`or a.authid='PUBLIC'`" is needed to include those privileges coming from **PUBLIC**.

```
SELECT distinct p.AUTHID, p.PRIVILEGE, p.OBJECTNAME, p.OBJECTSCHEMA, p.OBJECTTYPE   
FROM SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES P, SYSIBMADM.AUTHORIZATIONIDS A,   
     TABLE (SYSPROC.AUTH_LIST_GROUPS_FOR_AUTHID('userID')) as U  
WHERE p.privilege='CREATEIN' and a.authidtype='G' and a.authid=p.authid
AND (u.group=a.authid or a.authid='PUBLIC')
```

Comment: cool, thanks Henrik.  I got what I needed based on your suggestion. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Yes, Henrik.  It's very nice that your update answer my other question that 'how to get default group public issue'.  :-)

Comment: I actually created a blog entry out of it with an additional SELECT statement. See here http://blog.4loeser.net/2016/11/db2-security-implicit-privileges.html

Comment: What about nested groups? Will this handle the case when the user is in a child group, and the parent has the privilege?

Comment: Try it out and report back. :)